# We will get [back to you] as soon as we have more [information to share]

Tags: sentence-construction

> We will get ***back to you*** as soon as we have more ***information
>   to share***.

Is this sentence construction, is it OK as per the sentence construction parameter I have in my audit sheet?

It seems slightly off the track, but not sure what it is?

Comment: The sentence seems perfectly fine to me. But if you want us to comment on if it matches a required parameter of your audit sheet, you'll have to let us know what that is.

Comment: I think your question is possibly a little bit broad, questions asking for someone to find and correct errors or improve the phrasing are considered requests for proofreading and are off-topic.

Comment: The question is unclear because we don't know what you mean by "sentence parameter" or "audit sheet". Maybe just ask if the sentence is correct. If you think it might be incorrect, but you aren't sure why you think so, I think you can just say that. I don't think most of us would consider it *proofreading.*